# In EASA, what is Panel 12? Is this just the same as Panel 10?

Tags: safety, easa-regulations

IN EASA safety approval guidance, particularly [CM – SWCEH – 001
*Development Assurance of Airborne Electronic Hardware*](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/certification-docs-certification-memorandum-EASA-CM-SWCEH-001-Development-Assurance-of-Airborne-Electronic-Hardware.pdf), the entity charged with making sure that a system meets applicable requirements and guidelines (especially concerning safety) is called "Panel 10."

However, in section  5.2 "Background" there is a list of panels, and there, Safety is listed as Panel 12.  (Immediately after this list comes most of the assurance-related material, which extensively speaks of Panel 10.)  Yet no other mention of Panel 12 is made in this document.

Is this just a typo, where they meant Panel 10, not Panel 12?

Answer (score 1):

Reading through CM-SWCEH-001, the Background section is identifying the EASA system panels, one of which is identified as the primary panel for certification requirements for the system being developed. My understanding of Panel 10 is that it serves as a secondary panel for some of those requirements.

The document defines Panel 10 as:

> The EASA panel in charge of software and AEH aspects of certification.
>   This panel includes at least one software and AEH expert (the
>   coordinator) and, depending on the size of the project, may include
>   additional software and AEH experts.

I would say that it is not a typo, with Panel 12 being the System Saftey panel.